# Trying to fire a API.graphql aws-amplify createPost mutation on button click returns error

Tags: javascript, graphql, next.js, aws-amplify

I have this working on a page and a form, I am able to create a post, but I want to create the post with some default values and automatically take you to the edit page on a button press.

I am using next js aws-cdk, amplify, graphql,

The error I am getting is this

```
Variable 'post' has coerced Null value for NonNull type 'PostInput!'
```

I can't seem to figure out why I can create a post from a page button click but not from a button click in a component and reroute me to the edit page

this is the code that is working

create-post.js

```
// pages/create-post.js
import { withAuthenticator } from "@aws-amplify/ui-react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { API } from "aws-amplify";
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import SimpleMDE from "react-simplemde-editor";
import "easymde/dist/easymde.min.css";
import { createPost } from "../graphql";

const initialState = { title: "", content: "" };

function CreatePost() {
  const [post, setPost] = useState(initialState);
  const { title, content } = post;
  const router = useRouter();
  function onChange(e) {
    console.log(e.target.name + " " + e.target.value);
    setPost(() => ({ ...post, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }));
    console.log(post);
  }
  async function createNewPost() {
    if (!title || !content) return;
    const id = uuid();
    post.id = id;

    console.log(post);

    await API.graphql({
      query: createPost,
      variables: { post },
      authMode: "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS",
    });
    router.push(`/posts/${id}`);
  }
  return (
    <div style={containerStyle}>
      <h2>Create new Post</h2>
      <input
        onChange={onChange}
        name="title"
        placeholder="Title"
        value={post.title}
        style={inputStyle}
      />
      <div>
        {/* <input
          onChange={onChange}
          name="ingredients"
          placeholder="Ingredient"
          value={post.ingredients}
          style={inputStyle}
        /> */}
        <p>cups</p>
        <input name="measurments" type="radio" value="cups" />
        <p>tablespoons</p>
        <input name="measurments" type="radio" value="tablespoons" />
        <p>ML</p>
        <input name="measurments" type="radio" value="ml" />
        <p>Weight</p>
        <input name="measurments" type="radio" value="weight" />
      </div>
      <SimpleMDE
        value={post.content}
        onChange={(value) => setPost({ ...post, content: value })}
      />
      <button style={buttonStyle} onClick={createNewPost}>
        Create Post
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

const inputStyle = {
  marginBottom: 10,
  height: 35,
  width: 300,
  padding: 8,
  fontSize: 16,
};
const containerStyle = { padding: "0px 40px" };
const buttonStyle = {
  width: 300,
  backgroundColor: "white",
  border: "1px solid",
  height: 35,
  marginBottom: 20,
  cursor: "pointer",
};

export default withAuthenticator(CreatePost);
```

graphql.js

```
export const getPostById = /* GraphQL */ `
  query getPostById($postId: ID!) {
    getPostById(postId: $postId) {
      id
      title
      content
      owner
    }
  }
`;

export const listPosts = /* GraphQL */ `
  query ListPosts {
    listPosts {
      id
      title
      content
      owner
    }
  }
`;

export const postsByUsername = /* GraphQL */ `
  query PostsByUsername {
    postsByUsername {
      id
      title
      content
      owner
    }
  }
`;

export const createPost = /* GraphQL */ `
  mutation CreatePost($post: PostInput!) {
    createPost(post: $post) {
      id
      title
      content
      owner
    }
  }
`;

export const updatePost = /* GraphQL */ `
  mutation UpdatePost($post: UpdatePostInput!) {
    updatePost(post: $post) {
      id
      title
      content
      ingredients
    }
  }
`;

export const deletePost = /* GraphQL */ `
  mutation DeletePost($postId: ID!) {
    deletePost(postId: $postId)
  }
`;
```

this is the code that isn't working

hello compoenent
**THIS IS THE PART THAT IS NOT WORKING**

```
import { withAuthenticator } from "@aws-amplify/ui-react";
import { Auth, Hub, API } from "aws-amplify";
// import { API } from "aws-amplify";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";
import { createPost } from "../graphql";
const initialState = { title: "Title Here", content: "Content Here" };

function Hello() {
  async function createNewPost() {
    // if (!title || !content || !ingredients) return;
    const id = uuid();
    initialState.id = id;
    console.log(initialState);

    await API.graphql({
      query: createPost,
      variables: initialState,
      authMode: "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS",
    });
    router.push(`/edit-post/${id}`);
  }

  return (
    <button style={buttonStyle} onClick={createNewPost}>
      Create Post
    </button>
  );
}

const buttonStyle = {
  width: 300,
  backgroundColor: "white",
  border: "1px solid",
  height: 35,
  marginBottom: 20,
  cursor: "pointer",
};

export default withAuthenticator(Hello);
```

app with button to click

```
import "../configureAmplify";
import "../styles/globals.css";
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";
import "../configureAmplify";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Auth, Hub, API } from "aws-amplify";
// import { API } from "aws-amplify";
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";
import { createPost } from "../graphql";
import Hello from "../components/hello";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const [signedInUser, setSignedInUser] = useState(false);
  //const [post, setPost] = useState(initialState);
  //const { title, content, ingredients } = post;

  //setPost(initialState);

  useEffect(() => {
    authListener();
  });
  async function authListener() {
    Hub.listen("auth", (data) => {
      switch (data.payload.event) {
        case "signIn":
          return setSignedInUser(true);
        case "signOut":
          return setSignedInUser(false);
      }
    });
    try {
      await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
      setSignedInUser(true);
    } catch (err) {}
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <nav style={navStyle}>
        <Link href="/">
          <span style={linkStyle}>Home</span>
        </Link>
        <Hello />
        {signedInUser && (
          <Link href="/my-posts">
            <span style={linkStyle}>My Posts</span>
          </Link>
        )}
        <Link href="/profile">
          <span style={linkStyle}>Profile</span>
        </Link>
      </nav>
      <div style={bodyStyle}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const navStyle = { padding: 20, borderBottom: "1px solid #ddd" };
const bodyStyle = { minHeight: "calc(100vh - 190px)", padding: "20px 40px" };
const linkStyle = { marginRight: 20, cursor: "pointer" };

export default MyApp;
```

Comment: check network request ... bad variables structure passed

Comment: never knew I could even look in there. I looked at what the other one was passing and needed to pass the state with a post key `{post: initialState}` thanks!